# HTML Page content to Excel Sheet using Javascript/Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, excel

I have made a dashboard using html, css, bootstrap, javascript and jquery which is dynamically pulling data from a SharePoint list. I have all the data ready. All I need to do is to export the dashboard as is and display the data into an Excel sheet. I am stuck. Please help.

I have used arrays, variables and Json objects to store the data. I just need to map it into an Excel sheet.

Note: My dashboard contains text, tables and charts (created using chart.js)

Comment: So you have an Object or Array with the Data? Convert it to CSV maybe? Excel is pretty good in reading that format ;) Not sure what to do with your charts though ... https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/excel/excel-add-ins-charts

Comment: Thanks Roko C.Buljan. But if that is the case then i would have to create a workbook with multiple sheets within it to store different elements of the dashboard in a tabular format ( since the example link you suggested converts a table into a chart). I am fairly new at working with excel through javascript. Is there any site with detailed code that I can go through which would show me in detail how to create an excel workbook with multiple sheets and populate data into them. Thanks for your time :)